# Angular Property 'offsetWidth' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

new to angular, I am trying to use ScrollTrigger for horizontal scroll.

It work, but when I serve or build I got the error :
Property 'offsetWidth' does not exist on type 'Element'.

This is the code for the gsap :

```
gsap.to(sections, {
  xPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1),
  ease: "none",
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".panel-container",
    pin: true,
    scrub: 1,
    snap: 1 / (sections.length - 1),
    end: () => "+=" + document.querySelector(".panel-container").offsetWidth
  }
});
```

Even if I get the error it work, when I console log the "document.query.." I got the good width of the element.

But the error prevent me to ng build.
I already did the cast thing, first with :

```
let myElem = document.querySelector(".panel-container").offsetWidth as HTMLElement;
```

Or with  before but this don't work, I have the line with red underline with error message :
Conversion of type 'string' to type 'HTMLElement' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.

My angular project is 10.0.5.

Tried the solution in reply :

```
(document.querySelector(".panel-container") as HTMLElement).offsetWidth;
```

But got this error on red underline, but nothin in console when I ng serve.

> Conversion of type 'Element' to type 'HTMLElement' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
> Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 105 more.ts(2352)

Comment: you have to write it like `(document.querySelector(".panel-container") as HTMLElement).offsetWidth` otherwise you are telling TS to use `offsetWidth` as HTMLElement, which can't work.

Comment: Ty, I edit the reply with the error I get because not enought characters in reply ^^

Comment: also check this here, this describes another solution: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34694

Answer (score 35):

Try typing the expected output from `querySelector`.

That is:

```
document.querySelector<HTMLElement>(".panel-container").offsetWidth
```

Comment: is <HTMLElement> used as a generic here?

Answer (score 0):

The result can be null, so if you have strictNullChecks enabled you need to perform a null check first:

if (element !== null) { ... }

Comment: No, this would be a different error.